# Jetpack compose animation animateFloatAsState with vararg value like Valueanimator

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I hope to implement an animation that change scale value to remind the user that a widget can be clicked. In the past, I could use `Valueanimator`:

```
ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.8f,0.5f,0.8f,1.2f,0.6f,0.8f) //animateFloatAsState only support to define target value,init value
```

In jetpack compose,I had to came up with this implementation

```kotlin
    val animate = remember { Animatable(0.8f) }

    val playCheckItemAnimation = {
        scope.launch {
            animate.stop()
            for (i in 0..2) {
                animate.animateTo(0.8f)
                animate.animateTo(0.5f)
                animate.animateTo(0.8f)
                animate.animateTo(1.2f)
                animate.animateTo(0.6f)
                animate.animateTo(0.8f)
            }
        }
    }
```

If I need to set a group of float like `ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.8f,0.5f,0.8f,1.2f,0.6f,0.8f)`,there seems to be no convenient way.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rememberInfiniteTransition`. Check out more about animations in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#rememberinfinitetransition)

```
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val value by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
    0.5f,
    0.8f,
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = tween(durationMillis = AnimationConstants.DefaultDurationMillis),
        repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
    )
)
Box(
    Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .size(100.dp)
        .alpha(value)
        .background(Color.Red)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Than you for your answer,but if I need to set a group of float like `ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.8f,0.5f,0.8f,1.2f,0.6f ...etc)`,there seems to be no convenient way,`animateFloat`just support start and end value

Comment: @Notsfsssf, then you should update your question because it seems to be only about the two value animation. Do you want it to be infinite, or just a list of floating values?

Comment: I need animation with vararg floating values so I can change widget scale size flexibly

Comment: @Notsfsssf I doubt there is a way to improve your code. Sure, you could create a list of values and go over it with `forEach(animate::animateTo)` instead of adding a new line for each value, but not generally. Are you sure that [spring animation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#spring) doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This API doesn't exist but you can build one yourself relatively simply:

```
suspend fun <T, D : AnimationVector> Animatable<T, D>.animateTo(
    vararg value: T,
) {
    value.forEach {
        this.animateTo(
            targetValue = it,
            animationSpec = animationSpec
        )
    }
}
```

usage

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val animate = remember { Animatable(0.8f) }
val playCheckItemAnimation = {
    scope.launch {
        animate.stop()
        repeat(2) {
            animate.animateTo(0.8f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1.2f, 0.6f, 0.8f)
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily add extra args to `animateTo` like `animationSpec` etc as well.